# Facebook Like Buttons load very slowly

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, performance

I got this website: [All things I like](http://allthingsilike.com) and up until recently it was working perfectly. But suddenly it needs 20 seconds to load - I haven't touched the code in that time.
What could be the cause of this? 20 seconds is really long time.

I am using FBML implementation and not IFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked it on [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Well i checked and your total load time was 28.9 seconds. And most noticeable amount of time was spend on waiting for resources (for Fans and likes boxes) from static.ak.fbcdn.net and then getting them.

So there seem to be no problem from your site its the Facebook Server thats taking time in fetching the data and sending it back to your page.

You can still optimize your own resources like backgrounds ets.. i notice a big 100x200 image for header

Answer (score 0):

Super slow with facebook is annoying!

I stumbled across this page looking for a solution - the only one i cant think of (and hence, the one i'm going to enact) is to pre-size the div that the fb stuff will appear in. Page will still load slow, but won't readjust itself after 10 seconds!